# Why bootstrap 3.3.7 request size only 23.6kb, but actual size is 123 kb

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When I watch the request css file of the [bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/), it's only 23.6kb, but the actual size is 123kb, how it compress it to 23.6kb, is it the server side configuration?

- [The request size of bootstrap.min.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35zNc.jpg)
- [Open the request bootstrap.min.css in new chrome tab and save as the css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw8ZD.jpg)
- [The actual size is 123kb on disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0IO9.jpg)

Comment: Http Compression? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Comment: I will try that, thank you!!